# Uncaught Error: Script error for "core.js" - Trying simple console log from module

Tags: javascript, module, runtime-error, requirejs

I'm making a Chrome extension and therefore trying to use require.js, but unsuccessful to "require" the first file to be load.
**What i am doing wrong?**

---

### Project details

**Error:**

[image: Console Error]

**Project structure:**

[image]

**app.js:**

```
var jq = $.noConflict(true);
function docReady() {

    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: 'app',
        paths: {

        }
    });

    require(['core'], function(core) {
        core.log();
    });
}

jq(document).ready(docReady);
```

**core.js:**

```
define(function () {
    var methods = {};
    methods.log = function() {
        console.log('testing...');
    }

    return methods;
});
```

*Yes, i do load **require.js** in **content_scripts** inside the **manifest.json**, before loading **app.js***

I'm trying to do something simple as displaying a console.log from my second file, but after so many tries idk what to do.
**May someone help me?**

Comment: is your manifest loading the `core.js` before or after the content load event?

Comment: Are there are issues in the dev tools network panel?

Comment: i thought only the main file should be loaded in the manifest and everything else will be loaded "as needed", when needed by requirejs. I tested it and it worked. thank you @DeanVanGreunen!

Comment: Also i hate when the documentation doesn't describe this kind of information as what i have infer from requirejs documentation is that other scripts would be loaded only when i require them. Therefore i have only loaded in manifest the main js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest needs to loading the `core.js` before or after the content load event